# CSF/LFD - would I really need CPHulk enabled also?

Tags: security, firewall, denial-of-service

So if I have the default configuration of CSF/LFD firewall running, should I enable CPHulk, or does CSF/LFD already do what CPHulk does?

If the answer is "No, CSF/LFD does not do what CPHulk does", is there a way for me to change the CSF/LFD settings to make it work the same as CPHulk would?

Answer (score 1):

CPHulk and CSF/LFD are not the same.  CPHulk works at the PAM (Pluggable Authentication Module) level and if you use dovecot for mail, it also protects the email from brute force attacks.

CPHulk blocks the login to WHM/Cpanel but not the access to the website.
CSF/LFD blocks the traffic to your website. 
So, you could block large ip ranges with CPHulk without worrying about losing traffic from those ips ranges.

Also, CPHulk uses a MySQL table, so some people says it uses more resources.

Bottom line, unless you are experience performance issues, you could use both

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you can disable CPHulk if you have enabled CSF/LFD. A simple Internet search shows this question has been asked very often.